# Is it possible to enable some kind of "data available event" on NI-VISA for TCP/IP SOCKET resource?

Tags: python, c, ctypes, tcp, visa

For Serial resource (Serial COM port) I enable VI_EVENT_ASRL_CHAR event. (After this event I'm checking for available data in buffer with reading attribute VI_ATTR_ASRL_AVAIL_NUM and reading all data from buffer)

For TCP/IP I'm connecting to i.e.'TCPIP0::192.168.200.200::54321::SOCKET' resource. So how I could get ant event which will tell me about available data in receiving buffer?

I need an event because I'm receiving binary data without termination character and with variable data size.

I'm using PYTHON, ctypes and visa32.dll

Comment: How whould a "data available event" help you around the problem, that you do not know how much data you need to read? Or would the connection be closed by the peer after all data had been sent?

Comment: It will be used for binary transparent data transmission. If any data is available I should read it and pass to higher layers for data analysis. Right now I'm doing what using twisted. And trying to find an away to use NI VISA for that.